# Read a few Gatt characteristics at same time

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Trying read two Gatt characteristics at same time (sending read request one by one), but getting `onCharacteristicRead` just one time. What the problem? Thnx.

Comment: You have to perform read characteristics in **queues** and **synchronized** manner.

Comment: Android BLE stack is not powerful as iOS.

Comment: seriously in android we can not read two or more characteristic at time. we have to synchronized it .they have to solve it .

Comment: Actually, Its more depends on BLE stack of Android current version which is in early stage of development.

Comment: Anyone, a sample code that shows how to do it?

Comment: @MichaelKariv you shold organize your own commands stack in the way you want. I used `android.os.Handler` for that